# HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process) Troubleshooting steps: Check the system event log for error messages

Tags: .net

I'm getting this error when I'm going to deploy a asp .net core 8 project on my local IIS server, I'm getting Http 500.0 error

I'm getting this error at my local end and I have tried to resolve it at many way but I'm not able to resolve it successfully.

[image]

Comment: this is more generic error. You need to check the Event Viewer for details about this error. After that only you can fix that